# getting "No qualifying bean of type is defined."

Tags: spring, ioc-container, autowired

I am getting exception -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.muztaba.service.VerdictServiceImpl] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
at com.muztaba.service.App.task(App.java:35)
at com.muztaba.service.App.main(App.java:28)
```

This is the class from where I am getting there exception.

```
@Component
public class App {

QueueService<Submission> queue;

Compiler compiler;

VerdictService verdictService;

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    new App().task();
}

private void task() {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    queue =  context.getBean(QueueImpl.class);
    compiler = context.getBean(CompilerImpl.class);
    verdictService = context.getBean(VerdictServiceImpl.class); //here the exception thrown. 

    while (true) {
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Submission submission = queue.get();
            compiler.submit(submission);
        }
    }
}
}
```

First two variable injected properly but the verdictService is not. 
this is my `VerdictService` and `VerdictServiceImpl` interface and class.

```
public interface VerdictService {
    void post(Verdict verdict);
}
```

==

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class VerdictServiceImpl implements VerdictService {

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public void post(Verdict verdict) {
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
              .save(verdict);
}
}
```

and this is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.muztaba")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

I have also give my project directory structure.

[image]

What I am missing here ? thank you.

Comment: is your VerdictServiceImpl  in "com.muztaba" or sub packages?

Comment: @kuhajeyan VerdictServiceImpl is in `com.muztaba.service` package

Answer (score 1):

You need to autowire `VerdictService`

```
@Autowired
VerdictService verdictService;
```

and you need to omit the line

```
verdictService = context.getBean(VerdictServiceImpl.class);
```

Ideally your code should use the services via autowiring.

Comment: I wouldn't say the last sentence is a general rule; but since the OP autowired sessionFactory it seems like a standard in the project/company, so it's ok in this case.

Answer (score 1):

it seems since you have annotated it with @transactional, Spring is creating a JDK interface based proxy. **So spring manages a bean 'VerdictService' not 'VerdictServiceImpl'.**

it should be

**`verdictService = context.getBean(verdictService.class);`**

instead of

```
verdictService = context.getBean(VerdictServiceImpl.class);
```

Comment: cotext.getBean(VerdictSerivce.class) cause this exception `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.muztaba.service.VerdictService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: getbean,verdictServiceImpl`

Comment: I don't know but it works in this way - `verdictService = (VerdictService) context.getBean("verdictServiceImpl");`.  How could first two work but it was not work ? :(